# QGIS i.landsat.toar not reading .txt file

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am having an issue with GRASS i.landsat.toar tool.  It will not let me choose my metadata .txt file.  I click on the three dots to the right of "Name of Landsat metadata file (.met or MTL.txt) [optional]" (image 1).  I browse to where my metadata is stored (image 2), but it is not there.  The only option for file selection is .met.  I look in my folder and the MTL.txt file is clearly there (image 3).  I do not understand why QGIS will not let me pick the .txt file type (image 2)?  I am using QGIS 3.6.3 with GRASS 7.6.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edits:

I installed QGIS 3.4.9 with GRASS 7.6.1 and was able to select all files to grab the MTL.txt file.  Though I recieve the error "Wrong or missing parameter value: Name of Landsat metadata file (.met or MTL.txt)".  So it seems that it is not reading my MTL.txt file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file extension from `MET Files (*.met)` to `All files (*.*)`

[image]

and then choose the MTL.txt file from the available files

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.4.5.

Comment: I edited my original post (image 2).  I do not have the option to select "All files(*.*)"

Comment: @Zman3 Try to use QGIS 3.4.9 LTR maybe it will solve the issue.

Comment: I just did, and I can get to the file, but there is still an error with the file.  See additional edits.

Comment: QGIS 3.10 - select `*MTL.txt` or `*.*` option is missing